# Ubuntu password no longer works after login

Tags: 22.04, login, sudo, password

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a laptop (dual boot with Win 11) and something weird happened to my password. I can only use it to login when I select a user (the booting GUI) and after that, things like `sudo` or password pop-ups don't work (the system claims I provide a wrong password). Some other observations:

- the user is a member of the sudo group (`groups`)
- login as the root user doesn't work either (`su -`), the only option here is the recover mode where the root's password works
- it happens for every new user I create (using the recovery mode) - new users work normally for a while then the problem reoccurs
- neither x11 nor wayland works
- `passwd` (recovery mode) doesn't help

EDIT - Recreating the user's home directory helps, but after a while the problem comes back.

Comment: This kind of behavior may be caused by keyboard layout settings

Comment: I'm almost sure that's not the case. It looks like there's some update in the background that messes the password/some tokens. Btw, I added a small update to the description.